# How to get apt-mirror to mirror the full repository

Tags: apt-mirror

I noted that apt-mirror does not copy the full repository. I would like to make it copy all of it. Any I idea how that can be done?

This is what is on the server for Xenial/Main

```
[DIR]   binary-amd64/   2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   binary-i386/    2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   debian-installer/   2015-12-02 22:22    -    
[DIR]   dep11/  2016-04-21 13:13    -    
[DIR]   dist-upgrader-all/  2016-04-16 18:13    -    
[DIR]   i18n/   2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   installer-amd64/    2017-12-01 16:17    -    
[DIR]   installer-i386/ 2017-12-01 16:17    -    
[DIR]   source/ 2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   uefi/   2015-11-02 23:53    -
```

This is what I got

```
[DIR]   binary-amd64/   2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   binary-i386/    2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   dep11/  2016-04-21 13:13    -    
[DIR]   i18n/   2016-04-21 19:39    -    
[DIR]   source/ 2016-04-21 19:39    -
```

Edit: 
 one thing I already found out. To include the debian-installer/ section, add in the mirror.list file

```
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubunut xenial main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer universe multiverse
```

This works because apt-mirror finds a packages.gz file there. With other folders this does not work, e.g. installer-amd64.

Comment: Did you ever find how to solve this? I have been having the same issue with Kali repos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596514/how-can-i-include-installer-files-in-kali-apt-mirror-config

Comment: @Kryptos no. Just the described workaround for that single case worked.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the following with bionic Ubuntu 18.04 and works:

```
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-amd64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-amd64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-amd64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

deb-i386 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb-i386 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb-i386 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse

deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer universe/debian-installer multiverse/debian-installer

deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer universe/debian-installer multiverse/debian-installer

deb-amd64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe/debian-installer
deb-amd64 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse/debian-installer

deb-i386 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main/debian-installer restricted/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse/debian-installer

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
clean http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Comment: Can you please descrb what the difference is. It looks like you added combinations of universe/multiverse/etc to the /debian-installer branch. My initial issue was that there are other items beside the debian-installer in the repository that I did not want to exlicitly list but still mirror. Maybe I misunderstood you answer

Comment: Honestly I can't describe this. I am new into this, and what I found out was that I also didn't had the full repo. This was an issue for my debian installer, and after adding this it was solved and the debian installer was able to find the files